# UITableview Set Multi Selection programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: MultiSelection]

In my storyboard app I can select the multiple selection during editing mode. But my other app where everything is done programmatically i can't seem to find out where to program this. Where can i set the Editing mode for UITableView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objective-C version:

```
[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
```

and Swift one:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

Comment: I can't believe i missed that. Thank you!